# Scrapy HTTP STATUS: 404

Tags: python, scrapy

I am scraping a URL using scrappy below is the code of spider. The issue is it is showing a 404 error, while on scrappy shell there is no 404 error.

In settings.py I have added user agent values `USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36"` and also `ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False`

```
import scrapy

class UsaFloridaScrapperSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name            = 'usa_florida_scrapper'
    start_urls      = ['https://www.txlottery.org/export/sites/lottery/Games/index.html/']
    

    def parse(self, response):
        print("HTTP STATUS: "+str(response.status))
```

Comment: If you drop the '/' at the end, it seems to work

Comment: @Wim Hermans Yes you saved my day it is working